# How to achieve Keyup event in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

**Code to listen keyboard event:**

```
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.tick);
```

**Function that triggers on keydown**

```
Solitaire.prototype.tick = function(e) {
   if(key.isPressed('tab')){
       console.log("X");
       //Perform Key Up Action
   }
};
```

**Todo**
I want to perform some operation when tab key is released ("keyup" in jQuery).

**Note:**
I use [keymaster.js](https://rawgithub.com/madrobby/keymaster/master/keymaster.js) to check which key is pressed.

Comment: While your question is not specifically related to easeljs, since you tagged it as such you may wish to also check this: https://github.com/javierj/EaselJS/blob/master/KeyboardDemo/DemoKeyboard.html

Comment: i checked that @McArthey. In that plugin, event triggers on key down.

Comment: I suppose it wasn't precise enough and would have been challenging to adapt.  I'm happy you had already seen it though.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
this.document.onkeyup = keyup;
function keyup(event) {
   /** you can access keyCode to determine which key was pressed**/
   var keyCode =  event.keyCode;
}
```

to access and work with keyup even. Tab KeyCode is 9